# Put multiple AutoSys jobs On Ice

Tags: autosys

Is it possible to put multiple jobs on ice, eg. using a wildcard for the job name?

Answer (score 0):

Not by using wildcards for the job name. You can use the Group or Application job definitions to put multiple jobs on ice. These support wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve multiple jobs using wildcards and use script to put each job on ICE